# Is there Anyway to have a Spinner Drop Down a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spinner

Is there anyway to create a customized spinner so that It just drops down a textView for the user to see. Nothing intricate, Just when you click on the spinner it drops down this TextView that can be filled with whatever text and that takes up most of the screen.

or would it be easier to have a button that somehow when clicked, drops down a textView?

Comment: Can you show what u want?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by Using a Toggle Button Instead of a Spinner, Here is my code for it

```
private void ButtonInstructionOnCheck(final ToggleButton button, final TextView textView, final String string){
    textView.setText(string);
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if(textView.isShown() == false){
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(textView.isShown() == true){
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```